# Why is this export command not exporting shell functions?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, variables, unix

I had a bulk data file.i want to split 100 file . i got export an error. Error came (export: Illegal option -f)

code:

```
data=`awk 'END {print NR}' $DATADIR/data_cst_name_basics.tsv`
echo $data
l_upto=`expr $data / 100`
echo $l_upto
split_filter () { { head -n 1 $DATADIR/data_cst_name_basics.tsv; cat; } > "$FILE"; }i
export -f split_filter
tail -n +2 $DATADIR/data_cst_name_basics.tsv | split --lines=$l_upto --filter=split_filter - $FILES/split_
```

Comment: You probably aren't actually using `bash`; exporting functions is not a standard feature.

Comment: @chepner https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-export It is, though?

Comment: What I mean is, it's not part of the POSIX standard, and there are shells that don't support `export -f`; the OP seems to be using one of them.

Comment: @chepner Ooooh, got it.